# github.io blocked ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, github-pages

All my apps with ajax requests are return error: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. 
For example:
[https://zzharuk.github.io/local_weather_widget/](https://zzharuk.github.io/local_weather_widget/index.html)

```
function getWeather(location, value, callback) {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            appid:"3556435b983a95646ad9cab4a5ee0943",
            units: value,
            lat:location.latitude,
            lon:location.longitude
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
function LocalWeather() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (location) {
                getWeather(location,"metric",function (data) {
                    console.log(location);
                    console.log(data);
                 })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: change `http:/` to `https:/`

Comment: I did that at first, but :  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: https://zzharuk.github.io/local_weather_widget/index.html is 404 not found !

Comment: If you want to call a http url with a Ajax request with github pages, it's impossible. Github block your request if you try to request on a http url ... It's stupid but it's a fact

Comment: Have same problem!

Answer (score 1):

By reading [their prices list](http://openweathermap.org/price), you can see that SSL is only available for some paying subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

All it's asking you to do is use secure HTTP (HTTPS) instead of plain, unencrypted http.

So just change your url from

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
```

to

```
var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
```

Comment: "GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?callback=jQuery224046119877…a95646ad9cab4a5ee0943&units=metric&lat=50.4333&lon=30.5167&_=1468842084713 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: are you using Chrome? What happens in Firefox / IE? net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED seems to be a browser/firewall/proxy type issue. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=net%3A%3AERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED&oq=net%3A%3AERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.206j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8